# How to insert a section of HTML Code into a larger, HTML document

Tags: html, syntax

Im trying to understand how to insert a section of HTML into a larger doccument.
Im building a website with a sidebar containing a news section and a few links, the whole sidebar is manual, and is copy/pasted to each page, i want to make a system where i insert the code into the webpage from a master document, so changing a master will affect all pages importing it, i dont want to make the news page a seperate web page, imported by something like iframe, any sugjestions would be super apreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need server-side code or a static site generator (like Jekyll).

Comment: Looking into it right now!

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `<iframe>` tag to embed the page into the other page

Example:

```
<iframe src="https://google.com"> </iframe>
```